# node.js game server framework?

Tags: node.js

Is there a game server framework for Node.js? I was using nowjs, but I'd like something more geared toward games. While I'd prefer free/open source, i'm willing to look into commercial also. The only requirement I have is that it has to be node.js based.

Comment: Not really but you can [look at Maple.js](https://github.com/bonsaiden/maple.js)

Comment: that looks interesting. I'll take a look at it. Definitely doesn't support what I need, but it may be a good place to start

Comment: @Raynos, add your comment as an answer, I decided to build off that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Maple.js](https://github.com/bonsaiden/maple.js) is a solid starting point for a multiplayer node based game.

The ground architecture has been done and you can check out any other games by [Ivo Wetzel](https://github.com/BonsaiDen) to get some inspiration.

Answer (score 11):

Try [Pomelo.js](http://pomelo.netease.com/index.html) . A distributed game server framework for node.js

Comment: The problem with Pomelo is its an incredibly big and complicated framework with little english documentation other than a cursory explaination of some of the parts. Its very hard to orient to because theres just no good support in english.

Comment: I managed to get it running but like many here, I had a really hard time setting it up. Along the way, many issues propped up and very little to no support. At this point, I am better off using something more simple in order to make any progress.

Comment: Pomelo looks like good framework, but different issues happen sometimes. And the biggest problem appears here - the most part of community is located in China, all forums and issues discussions are in Chinese... It's almost impossible to understand something if you don't know Chinese...

Comment: The link errors with 403.

Answer (score 4):

Have played around with [Osmus](https://github.com/borismus/osmus). Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

> Disclaimer: I am the author of this experimental game networking framework.

I would recommend checking [Nexy](https://github.com/majimboo/nexy). It can help you write modular game servers.

> Nexy is a middleware based TCP framework for Node. Written for Multiplayer Games.

The design is inspired by Connects and Express middleware system and those patterns are already proven in production.

Try it with `npm install nexy`.

Answer (score 1):

shellyjs - sync and async, user reg, stats, object storage, clustering, default turn based game module, player matching, email, connect4 and tictactoe examples, HTTP, WebSocket, and TCP

https://npmjs.org/package/shellyjs

disclosure - I work on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/). There is [example](http://type4fame.com/) of game on Derby.

Answer (score -1):

Pomelo is a much better game server framework.
It developed much better than other framework. It is much more scalable, can hold many online users.  you can see it on github:

https://github.com/NetEase/pomelo